# Java - Serializable Image is black when transferred over sockets

Tags: java, image, sockets, awt, serializable

I am sending Images through sockets in Java, and when both client and server are on one computer all is well, but when I run it over LAN, the resulting image is black. I take an image of the screen with the Robot class, then scale it down with AffineTransform.
Client code:

```
        BufferedImage s = null;
        socket = new Socket("AJ-PC", 4444);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        Robot r = new Robot();
        while(true) {
              s = r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
              double scale = 0.75;
              int w = (int) (s.getWidth() * scale);
              int h = (int) (s.getHeight() * scale);
              BufferedImage outImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);                
              AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
              trans.scale(scale, scale);
              Graphics2D g = outImage.createGraphics();
              g.drawImage(s, trans, null);
              g.dispose();
              Thread.sleep(400);
              out.writeObject(new SerializableImage(outImage));
       }
```

Server code:

```
        server = new ServerSocket(4444);
        socket = server.accept();
        System.out.println(socket);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while(running) {
            bi = (SerializableImage) in.readObject();
            b = true;
            System.out.println("new");
            panel.repaint();
        }
```

Comment: SerializableImage is a non-JDK class. Where does it come from?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I am using the PsExec utility from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx, and that seems to be the problem. when I don't use this to execute remotely, it runs fine.